# [Autoware.Auto] GNSS conversion node not starting

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run the GNSS conversion node that converts the GNSS data from WGS_84 to ECEF co-ordinates. When I try to run the node for experimentation using

`ros2 run gnss_conversion_nodes gnss_conversion_nodes_exe`

I get the following error

`1640158244.062340 [0] gnss_conve: using network interface wlp111s0 (udp/192.168.0.8) selected arbitrarily from: wlp111s0, docker0, br-2d7f79e3ae0b`

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'`

`what():  Override covariance must have exactly 3 entries.`

It seems to be the problems with the parameters not being read properly, but I am not able to figure out how to solve this and run the node correctly.  Any help in resolving this or any direction to proceed for debugging would be great. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393208/%5Bautoware.auto%5D-gnss-conversion-node-not-starting/) by [sujithvemi](https://answers.ros.org/users/86729/sujithvemi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2021-12-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Setting the params from the param file solved this issue. I missed the param file already provided for this node in Autoware.Auto and got confused.

---

Originally posted by [sujithvemi](https://answers.ros.org/users/86729/sujithvemi/) with karma: 46 on 2021-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-29**:
Hi @sujithvemi. Thank you for providing answer